# Static background image with transparent content

Tags: html, css

This is a question for the CSS gurus. A trend at the moment seems to be to place an image in the background and then have a transparent content scroll over the top.

**AIM**

What technique is used to produce this result, where the top content is transparent and slides over a background image.

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/2uUEL/9/embedded/result/

**MY ATTEMPT**

What I have tried to do is apply a background and then make the top section transparent on top of it.

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/N9sCD/3/

```
body { 
    background-image"http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg"; 
}
#top {
    height: 160px;
    opacity:0.4; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
}
#section {
    height: 600px; background-color: blue;
}
```

**QUESTION**

How has this technique of a transparent div moving over a static background image been achieved in my first link and how can I reproduce it. It must be a CSS solution because it still works without javascript enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/27j6F/)**</kbd>

```
<div id="top">
  <span class="mask">
    <img src="https://app.h2ometrics.com/build/v0.1.1a/styles/img/chrome_logo.png" class="logo" alt="Chrome">
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </span>
</div>

<div class="section l">

</div>

<div class="section d">

</div>


#top {
  background:url(http://www.hdwallpapers3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/6.jpg) fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}
#top a {
  background: rgba(200,200,200,0.5);
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px 15px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #111;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: color 0.2s ease-in;
}
#top a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.mask {
  background: rgba(0,187,255,0.5); /* or hex combined with opacity */
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 8px -3px #666; /* makes #top little inset */
}
.logo {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.section {
  height: 600px;
}
.l {
  background: #ddd;
}
.d {
  background: #333;
}
```

**Update** `#top` content placed inside `.mask` which removes need for `z-index`.

Answer (score 1):

You were essentially correct in building but your CSS has some errors.

```
body { 
    background: url('http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg') fixed; /* fixed stops background from scrolling */
    background-size: cover cover; /* expands bg image to cover body */
}
#top {
    height: 160px;
    color: #fff; /* this just makes the text visible on your dark bg */
}
```

You don't need to set the opacity of #top because without a background set it will already be transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

HTML - pushed the menu into its own div

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="menu">
    logo
    link 1
    link 2
    </div>
</div>
<div id="section">

</div>
```

CSS - removed margin from body, set the background to a fixed position and to always cover the whole body, added background color to menu.  Note that #top does not need a transparency as it is 100% transparent by default.  If you want to get a 'colour washed' looking image it would be better to adjust the image itself rather than trying to re-create a colour overlay.

```
body { 
    margin: 0;
    background: url("http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/abstract_color_background_picture_8016-wide.jpg") fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
#top {
    height: 500px;
}
#menu {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#section {
    height: 600px; background-color: blue;
}
```